# swagger refuse to start the IIS after upgrade .net 2.0 to 3.0

Tags: .net, windows, visual-studio, iis

Web page displayed below error after i run the solution at visual studio.

```
HTTP Error 500.30 - ANCM In-Process Start Failure
```

what should I configure to make the swagger loaded?

the appsettings.development.json is not modified and working well at .net 2.0.

what else am i need to modify to it works?

Comment: .NET Core 2.0 to 3.0 is not simple, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio and Swagger might also have its own upgrade guide. So to learn what's up, you might start from a brand new .NET Core 3.0 project.

Comment: @lex the codes already upgraded. I believed its the. Net 3.0 installation files or anything else need to be configure manually in Windows. Because I run the codes by using docker dotnet 3.0, swagger up successfully. Just the iis at visual studio failed and displayed the error at page.

Comment: Did you see error message regarding this http error in event viewer?

Comment: Application '/LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT' with physical root 'C:\Test\' failed to load coreclr. Exception message:
CLR worker thread exited prematurely

Comment: The directory specified for caching compressed content C:\inetpub\temp\IIS Temporary Compressed Files\Test AppPool is invalid.  Static compression is being disabled.

Comment: Do you see stack trace there? it should tell us what the exception is.